# Exception when running lenskit-eval with the movielens dataset

Tags: groovy, lenskit

I'm trying to run the evaluation code in

http://lenskit.org/documentation/evaluator/quickstart/

but, after one minute or so, it finishes with an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Target "eval" does not exist in the project "null". 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.tsort(Project.java:1912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.topoSort(Project.java:1820)
    at org.grouplens.lenskit.eval.EvalProject.executeTargets(EvalProject.java:168)
    at org.grouplens.lenskit.eval.cli.EvalCLI.run(EvalCLI.java:91)
    at org.grouplens.lenskit.eval.cli.EvalCLI.main(EvalCLI.java:127)
```

I just downloaded and unzipped `ml-100k.zip`, put the `eval.groovy` script in the same directory and run

```
lenskit-eval eval
```

I'm using lenskit 2.2 on Java 7.

What am I missing?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the second `eval` - it tells the LensKit evaluator to try to run the eval target `eval`, which doesn't exist.

Either run:

```
lenskit eval
```

which is recommended, or the deprecated

```
lenskit-eval
```

Comment: Thank you for you help Michael, and sorry for the foolish question :$ I must have misread the documentation (and I know very little groovy). By the way, following your suggestion, I signed up in the mailing list a couple of days ago, but I didn't receive any reply. Is that OK? (I mean, is my "application" being processed or something like that?)